# Removing the footer from Confluence Documentation Theme

Tags: confluence, headers

I'm using [Atlassian Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview) 4.2.6 with the [Documentation Theme](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+the+Documentation+Theme) and would like to completely remove the footer (the thing on the bottom of e.g. [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+the+Documentation+Theme) page).

I know how to change the default text or hide the footer contents via Javascript/CSS, but I'd like to remove it completely, probably by changing the Velocity template (I tried that, but without success).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

- Extract the content of `%confluence_home%/bundled-plugins/doctheme-2.x.x.jar`
- Comment out the following line at the end of file `doctheme\decorators\main.vmd`:

  `##parse ("/decorators/includes/footer.vm")`
- zip the files again and upload he plugin

*Tested with Confluence 4.1.19 and doctheme-2.0.9.jar*

Answer (score 1):

It is against the [Atlassian end user agreement](https://www.atlassian.com/end-user-agreement/) to completely remove the footer (section 6.4 as of the time of writing "Attribution"):

> In any use of the Software, you must include the following attribution
>   to Atlassian on all user interfaces in the following format: “Powered
>   by Atlassian,” which must in every case include a hyperlink to
>   http://www.atlassian.com, and which must be in the same format as
>   delivered in the Software.